# How far does HttpContext.User.Identity propagate when calling a chain of web applications/APIs?

Tags: c#, microservices, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-2.1, httpcontext

We have a ASP.NET MVC application that sends the user information using Windows Authentication.  All the web APIs are setup to use windows authentication, and the app site has been added to the trusted intranet sites under Internet Options (this is to ensure that windows sends the user information with the calls).

This application talks to a Service Bus that then communications to all the various micro-services.  Currently, there are 10+ web APIs covering various domains of the application.

When checking the user (via HttpContext.User.Identity), we see the user information (Identity w/ user name) on the Bus.  Once the bus calls to another web API, we then lose the identity.

Is there a limit to how far along a chain of calls the Identity will propagate?

**More Info**

- All the APIs are currently running on the same windows server with different app pools.
- The server is in the same domain as the clients.
- This is an **intranet** application.

Comment: Services will be running as a specific user - Local System or Local Service, usually, unless you specify otherwise.  If you want to pass user identity info when you send something from a service then you'll have to include it in the payload.  Typically, you could have a base class that all your messages inherit (and force implementation when receiving), and make that require user information.

Comment: Then why would the Service Bus get the user information?

Comment: Without seeing any code it's impossible to answer.  I have no idea why a service would even have any idea what a HttpContext is.

Comment: What do you mean by "see the user on the bus"?

Comment: If they have different app pools then they're not services - they're web applications or web APIs.  Still, without seeing any code we can't answer why one application does something that the others can't.

Comment: @Archer, sorry mean web services/web APIs - will update

Comment: My understanding is that Windows sends the user information in with the call to the web api.

Comment: @DavidG, sorry meant that we can see the user information (ex: user name).  Updated post.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/kerberos-authentication-overview Behind the scene you need to have Kerberos delegation.